# Mate download links broken?

Tags: apache2, downloads, mate

For some reason I can't download the newest Mate version. All links and options are not working or can't be found on Apache server. I have a reliable internet connection and my laptop is plugged in, I don't get it. Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks, cweklund

Comment: The Magnet link in your favorite Bittorrent client should work as always. Others, both the actual Torrent file and the direct download seem to have a problem indeed but should be temporary.

Comment: Can you get the file from the [iso testing tracker](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/437/builds/255683/testcases) (reliably via zsync)?